# What is the period in the `FROM` clause of a sql statement?

Tags: sql

I have this nested SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    SalesOrderID,
    LineTotal,
    (SELECT AVG(LineTotal)
     FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail) AS AverageLineTotal,
    LineTotal - (SELECT AVG(LineTotal)
                 FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail) AS Variance
FROM   
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

What is `Sales.SalesOrderDetail` referring to? How does this table look?

Is there a `Sales` table?

Does

```
LineTotal - (SELECT AVG(LineTotal)
             FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail) AS Variance
```

need parenthesis around it or no like this:

```
 (LineTotal - (SELECT AVG(LineTotal)
               FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail)) AS Variance
```

Comment: `Sales` is the schema and `SalesOrderDetail` is the table. Schema and table names are separated by a period.

Comment: A single database can contain multiple schemas. It is a way of logically grouping tables together.

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "." is used to separate different elements.

A table name in SQL Server consists of up to 4 elements:

- Server (you can address tables on a linked separate server)
- Database
- Schema Name
- Table Name

In your case, you have 2 elements - schema name and table name.

A schema is like a (one level) folder and is used to group coresponding elements (tables, views, everything). If you have a non trivial database (hundreds of tables), some organization is nice. This organizaton also allows you to set permissions on schema level, for example.

You can read more about schemata in the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-schema-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

SalesOrderDetail is table name and Sales is the schema name(under which SalesOrderDetail is created).

Sales is a schema name.

LineTotal - (SELECT AVG(LineTotal)
                    FROM   Sales.SalesOrderDetail) AS Variance
will work with parenthesis or without. Both will give same result.

Answer (score 0):

Sales is a Schema as like as dbo is too.

I changed Sales.SalesOrderDetail to @Sales_SalesOrderDetail only to be easier to show you understand the query.

The sub query below will calculate the average of LineTotal

SELECT AVG(LineTotal) FROM   @Sales_SalesOrderDetail)

```
declare @Sales_SalesOrderDetail table (SalesOrderID int identity , LineTotal int) 

insert @Sales_SalesOrderDetail(LineTotal) select 10
insert @Sales_SalesOrderDetail(LineTotal) select 20
insert @Sales_SalesOrderDetail(LineTotal) select 30
insert @Sales_SalesOrderDetail(LineTotal) select 40

SELECT SalesOrderID,
       LineTotal,
       (SELECT AVG(LineTotal)
          FROM   @Sales_SalesOrderDetail) AS AverageLineTotal,
       LineTotal - (SELECT AVG(LineTotal)
                    FROM   @Sales_SalesOrderDetail) AS Variance
FROM   @Sales_SalesOrderDetail
```

[image]

An alternative version of this code is:

```
declare @Sales_SalesOrderDetail table (SalesOrderID int identity , LineTotal int) 

insert @Sales_SalesOrderDetail(LineTotal) select 10
insert @Sales_SalesOrderDetail(LineTotal) select 20
insert @Sales_SalesOrderDetail(LineTotal) select 30
insert @Sales_SalesOrderDetail(LineTotal) select 40

DECLARE @AverageLineTotal int  = (SELECT AVG(LineTotal) FROM   @Sales_SalesOrderDetail) 


SELECT SalesOrderID,
       LineTotal,
       @AverageLineTotal,
LineTotal - @AverageLineTotal AS Variance


FROM   @Sales_SalesOrderDetail
```

The result is the same, but the performance is better because the AVG will be calculated only one time and not for each line.